# C++ app doesn't read json file - Docker container

Tags: c++, docker

i wrote a c ++ program that does calculations. The values ​​should be read from a JSON file and then stored in a variable.
I have now started this application in a Docker container (alpine). In the app, everything works except reading the data from the JSON file.
Outside the container, the program runs without problems.

What can this be? Does Docker need to specify a different directory for .JSON files? Or why could that be?

C++:

```
// filestream variable file 
std::fstream file; 
std::string word, filename;
std::string stringA= ""; 

// filename of the file 
filename = "TestX.json"; 

// opening file 
file.open(filename.c_str()); 

// extracting words form the file 
while (file >> word) 
{ 
    if((word.find("ABC",0))!=-1){
        file >> word;
        stringA= word;
    }

    if((word.find("CDE",0))!=-1){
        file >> word;
        stringB = word;
    }

    if((word.find("EFG",0))!=-1){
        file >> word;
        stringC = word;
    }

    if((word.find("GHI",0))!=-1){
        file >> word;
        stringD = word;
    }
}
```

DOCKER COMMAND:

```
docker run -it -p 8080:1234 test
```

Comment: Please add the docker command your are running, the Dockerfile and C++ code

Comment: Please do some minimal debugging. Check the return value of your program trying to open the file, print the errno, run strace, ...

Comment: One of the key features of Docker is _filesystem isolation_: your program in a container _can't_ see files on the host unless they're explicitly mapped in (or copied into an image in a Dockerfile).  It sounds like this is more likely an impediment than a feature for you; what benefits do you hope to get from Docker?